# Groovy: Usage of 'it' with closures

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I wonder how I can pass the implicit variable 'it' to the closure.
See the following code:

```
def myfunc(String name, Closure cl)
{
    println("name: ${name}")
    cl.call()
}

list = ['a', 'b']

list.each
{
    println("it1: ${it}")
}

list.each
{
    myfunc("f1")
    {
        println("it2: ${it}")
    }
}

list.each
{
    p ->
    myfunc("f2")
    {
        println("p: ${p}")
    }
}
```

The resulting output is:

```
it1: a
it1: b
name: f1
it2: null
name: f1
it2: null
name: f2
p: a
name: f2
p: b
```

How can I achieve that in the second version (f1/it2) the implicit variable `it` is passed to the closure? Currently it is "null".
I want to achieve to have 'a', 'b' within 'it' in the second version.

The background of the question is, that within a Jenkins Pipeline, the following code

```
    mylist = ['a1', 'a2']
    mylist.each {
        dir ("xxxx") {
            echo "it in xxxx is ${it}"
        }
    }
```

prints out the values 'a1' and 'a2' for `it`.
This does not fit to the understanding that `it` is bound to the outermost closure.

In case of Jenkins the behaviour seems to be different.
I want to achieve the very same behaviour and I am wondering how to do this.

Thanks for all feedback!

Best regards

Mathias

Comment: no way because there are two nested closures. `it` is a reference to current closure parameter and there is no way to access "parent" closure parameter.

Comment: As @dagget says, this is not possible.  However, I'm curious what you're trying to accomplish.  Why do you need to combine these values?  Perhaps someone here can help you solve your underlying problem if you can explain the goal.

Comment: I have extended my question. The behaviour within a Jenkins pipeline seems to be different from that what I get in my Groovy script.

Comment: `dir` from jenkins is not a function - it's a jenkins Step and your groovy function example is not applicable. you have to check if it's achievable from groovy-defined custom steps https://rubix.nl/jenkins-creating-a-custom-pipeline-step-in-your-library/ or think about custom plugin creation.

Comment: @daggett :  Thanks, this answers my question. Can you please place your comment as an answer so I can close the topic.

Comment: i've updated my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dir` from jenkins is not a function - it's a jenkins Step and your groovy function example is not applicable.

you have to check if it's achievable from groovy-defined custom steps https://rubix.nl/jenkins-creating-a-custom-pipeline-step-in-your-library/

or think about custom plugin creation.

btw, here is a source of `dir` jenkins step: https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/PushdStep.java

Comment: Thanks, I have extended my question to give more details on the background.